# Labels From Parse Won't Update -- Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm writing code that has an account page to show the user's name and their paycheck. I've managed to change the label "header" to the user's name, but I haven't been able to get the Number from payCurr to update my "paid" label. Do anyone know if I need to keep the current pay as a String in Parse for it to work? Writing String in the code runs, but doesn't change the label, but using Float gives the error "Cannot assign a value of type 'Float' to a value of type 'String?'. Is there a way to convert the type Number from the database to a String in Xcode?

I've also been having the issue of the label not reloading after I manually change the value of firstName or payCurr in Parse -- could this be some local data store I need to clear?

```
@IBOutlet weak var header: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var paid: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let payDB = PFUser.currentUser()?["payCurr"] as? Float {
        paid.text = payDB
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if let firstName = PFUser.currentUser()?["firstName"] as? String {
        self.header.text=firstName
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using currency you can use this code to convert the float to a String that reflect the currency settings in your phone

```
if let payDB = PFUser.currentUser()?["payCurr"] as? Float {
    let nf = NSNumberFormatter()
    nf.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    paid.text = nf.stringFromNumber(payDB)    
}
```

I hope that helps you!

Comment: Thanks so much! Just one more thing: how do I make the account page update the number on load to make sure the value is always up to date? I put the functions in the viewDidLoad as you can see, but the only way I have been able to reload the value is if I log out and log back in

Comment: a easy solution is to move from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear as view did load is not called when you segue back from another view but view will appear does

Comment: Yes, for whatever reason updating the label in a separate function, then calling the function in viewDidLoad updates it with a segue to the page.

Comment: @Maxwell that didn't work for me. I created a function named setLabel() where i set the text for a label.

I call that function within viewDidLoad using self.setLabel() but that didn't work... 

Anything else ?